# custum error reponse in json format in symfony

Tags: json, symfony, exception

i try to read a json data , so when the response with status ok (200) i can get data  correctly in json format , but the webservice return a message if there is no item to return so he generate a message like  that :

```
{"message " : "item not found" }
```

the problem is when symfony find that the response it not found he throw an exception not found while i want to just return the message that the webservice provide  .

this is my controller code:

```
/**
     *
     * @Get("/getUserByUid/{uid}")
     */
    public function getUserByUidAction($uid)
    {
        $url = self::Ws_URL . self::Ws_PORT . self::Ws_GetUserByUID . $uid;

        $headers = array() ;
        $headers[] = "auth_token: ".self::Ws_Token ;
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json" ;
        $arrContextOptions=array(
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
            "http" =>array(
                "method" => "GET",
                "header" => "auth_token: ".self::Ws_Token
            )
        );
        $response   = file_get_contents($url, true, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

        return New Response($response) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web service is RESTFull then return a http code 404 with the above message `{"message " : "item not found" }`, then `file_get_contents` does not fetch the content of the file because the 404 is saying `Does not exist`. To get the full response and http code use `curl` instead.